# Jenkins: run a powershell script with nohup via sshcommand

Tags: powershell, jenkins, nohup

I run a powershell script via `sshcommand`, the script itself runs several servers that listen on different ports:

```
sshCommand remote: remote_server, command: " powershell.exe C:/run_services.ps1"
```

It runs services one by one with no problem, I can see them on remote server, but as soon as `sshcommand` session is closed all services(processes) get terminated.

How can I run the script like `nohup` in linux to have them running?
I know a windows service can be written and started /stopped every time, but this solution seems way too time/effort consuming.